# If two curves are birationally equivalent does it imply they are rationally equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume we have two curves both being subvarieties of the same variety.
If they are birationally or rationally isomorphic, does it imply they are rationally equivalent? I believe that this is true. Because a curve is rationally equivalent to itself, so don't we get rational equivalence due to functoriality of rational equivalence?

Comment: Birational equivalence of varieties and rational equivalence of cycles *on* a variety are two different notions that are (more or less) unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean rational equivalence of cycles, the answer is no. For instance, on $\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$, there are two families of lines, $\{a\}\times\Bbb P^1$ and $\Bbb P^1\times\{b\}$. These represent the two generators of the Picard group $\Bbb Z^2$, and so they are not rationally equivalent (but they are isomorphic: they're both just copies of $\Bbb P^1$).